# Function to encoding input characters in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, sorting, vector

I want to create a function that *encrypts* the input sentence. This *encryption* will replace the first letter of each word with the next letter in the ASCII table, and the second letter with the next, ....

So basically, the resulting output for `abc def` should be `bcd efg`. However, when I run my function, the space will also be replaced, i.e. output will be `bcd!efg`. Why is this so? Thanks.

Below is what I have written:

```
function out = encrypt(input)
ascii_encode=double(input);
line={ascii_encode};
counter=0;

for a=1:length(line)
    if line{a}==32
        counter=0;
    else
        counter=counter+1;
        line{a}=line{a}+counter;  
    end   
    line{a}=char(line{a});
end        
out=line;
end
```

Comment: Unless you want to do more things later on, the use of cells is quite overkill and unnecessary in your case. You can work on strings (=char array) directly.

Comment: Although your question was answered you might want to consider edge cases as how the letter z gets encrypted. Maybe even consider numbers and punctuations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be careful handling *cells*.

Try `line{a}` , `line(a)` , `line(1){a}`, to understand how they work.

The code should be like this,

```
function out = encrypt(input)
ascii_encode = double(input);
line = {ascii_encode};
for a = 1 : length(line{1})
    if line{1}(a) == 32
       continue;
    end    
    line{1}(a) = line{1}(a) + 1;  
end        
line{1} = char(line{1});
out = line{1};
end
```

And there is no need for `counter`, you just have to jump when `if` is `true`.

Comment: Just realised the difference between using {} and () when dealing with cells. With regards to using counter, I previously didn't know of the line continue. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Kamtal's answer is perfectly right. You assign your input to a cell and then you were not accessing an index **in** the cell value (which is still a char array), but the full cell value.

Follow Kamtal answer if you still want to use cells type, and look at the [cell](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) documentation.

Note that you could also benefit by Matlab vectorization capabilities, and simplify your function by:

```
function out = encrypt(input)

charToKeep = ( input==' ' ) ; %// save position of character to keep
out = char(input+1) ;         %// apply the modification on the full string
out(charToKeep) = ' ' ;       %// replace the character we saved in their initial position

end
```